# Update Rails Model using hidden field without breaking MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Lesson Model and a Student Model in a Rails 3 app. When lesson prices are updated it affects an attribute in Student called 'balance.'

When I update the lesson price I want to pass in the old price via a hidden field. Then I've got a private method in the Lesson Model that looks like this..

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :student_id, :price

  belongs_to :student

  around_update :adjust_student_balance

  private

    def adjust_student_balance
      @student = Student.find(self.student_id)
      @student.balance -= @old_price
      yield
      @student.balance += self.price
      @student.update_attributes(:balance => @student.balance)
    end
end
```

As you can see I'm trying to (1) subtract the old price from the student's balance, (2) perform the update on the lesson and then (3) add the new price to the student's balance.

But the above code doesn't work because I'm attempting to access from the model the instance variable `@old_price` declared in the controller. After some searching I've realized not only will this not work, but it breaks an important precept of MVC.

How should I be doing this properly? Should I be doing everything in the controller? It seems like my controller is getting quite big already. I'm quite new at this, by the way.

Comment: You are using rails. The MVC has already been broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (untested) code:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :student_id, :price

  belongs_to :student

  after_save :adjust_student_balance

  private

  def adjust_student_balance
    student = self.student

    student.balance -= self.price_was
    student.balance += self.price

    student.save
  end
end
```

It uses `Active Model Dirty`. Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html for more information about this topic.

Comment: Awesome. Worked like a charm. One question though: The API you linked to said I would have to `include ActiveModel::Dirty`, but I didn't do that. So if the model inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` then is automatically gets all the Dirty functionality?

Comment: Yes. If you use the default stuff you'll always have access to Dirty.